# Is the Tea Party still a significant political force in the US?

Tags: united-states, parties, public-opinion

It seem unclear if this was its heyday, but Wikipedia [mentions that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_Party_movement):

> One 2013 survey found that, in political terms, 20% of self-identified Republicans stated that they considered themselves as part of the Tea Party movement.

Have there been any more recent similar polls on the Tea Party self-identification?  Or any other reasonably objective way to measure the Tea Party influence in US politics since then?

Comment: Hypothetically, if some of the tea party's ideas had been taken up by another, still relevant entity, would that count? Or are you specifically asking about the group that calls itself tea party?

Comment: @Peter: well, the Tea Party itself probably didn't come up with many new ideas of its own, so unless there's something really specific to them that got carried over, as opposed to something that they themselves borrowed and others used as well, it would probably not help much illuminating their influence/legacy.

Answer (score 3):

This is not very satisfying, but at least it is [a measure of activity](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/28/us/politics/tea-party-trump.html) of one of its largest sub-groups:

> At the height of its influence in 2011 and 2012, Tea Party Patriots was bringing in $20 million a year in contributions and employed 30 people, its tax records show. In 2017 it collected $4.8 million and had a staff of 15.

And at least some Tea Party exponents who thought the Tea Party stood for reducing the deficit, (e.g. [Matt Kibbe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Kibbe)) have [declared](https://reason.com/2018/02/11/the-tea-party-is-dead-long-live-liberty/) the Tea Party dead last year. Some people, on the left in particular, [disagree](https://www.motherjones.com/politics/2019/09/the-tea-party-got-what-it-wanted/) that that was what the Tea Party was mainly about. However, it was still a formally valid characterization: Tea Party Republicans distinguished themselves from the rest of Republicans on the intensity with which they viewed a number of issues. On a 2014 [Pew poll](https://news.gallup.com/poll/178814/tea-party-republicans-highly-motivated-vote-midterms.aspx), which might not have covered all the possible issues though, the budget deficit was the biggest difference (15 percentage points), followed by ACA (11 points).

Comment: I've heard other Tea Party activists declare the Tea Party dead as soon as Trump became the Republican nominee, using similar arguments as Kibbe but with different specific examples (mainly, the pressures that caused most of the Tea Party politicians to now blindly support Trump).